# discord.py list object has no attribute name

Tags: python, discord.py

```
acts = user.activities
act = [i for i in acts if isinstance(i, discord.CustomActivity)]
if act:
    act = act[0]
else:
    holy = (str("NONO"))
text = act.name
if text:
    holy = (f'Custom Status of {user.name}: **{text}**')

else:
    holy = ("상메가 X")
```

this is my code // it keeps say 'list' object has no attribute 'name'

how should it solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

In the seventh line you wrote `text = act.name`, but `act` is a list object (in second line).
I think you might want to change it to `user.name`.

Comment: i dont know how to fix it